# How to plot out of bound raster color scale with a specific color in image R?

Tags: r, plot, r-raster, rastervis

I have a raster and I want to plot the out of bound color with a specific color in image plot. The code I have so far

```
## read the libraries
library(raster)
library(fields)
library(grDevices)


##random raster object
set.seed(1)
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5)
r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r),mean=2)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
col = colorRampPalette(c("darkred","red","lightskyblue","blue","blue4"))(20)
##plot without any z limit
image(r, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", col= rev(col))
##plot with z limit
image(r, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", col= rev(col),zlim = c(min(r@data@values),2))
```

It looks like this

[image]

The first plot is a normal image plot without specifying any limits and the second plot with some limiting condition.
I want to change the white color (out of bound values i.e. raster values higher than 2) in my second plot with the first color of color palette ("darkred").

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom breaks with the `image` function to set the range of the highest display color group.

```
set.seed(1)
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5)
r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r),mean=2)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
col = colorRampPalette(c("darkred","red","lightskyblue","blue","blue4"))(20)
col = rev(col)

image(r, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", col = col, main="Initial")

breaks = seq(r@data@min, r@data@max, length.out=21)    
col[which(breaks[1:20] >= 2)] = col[20]
image(r, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", col = col, breaks=breaks, main="Z-Limit")
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. May be I didnt formulate the question in the right way. When you use the breaks the scale of plot also changes `par(mfrow=c(2,1));
##without any z limit;
image(r, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", col= rev(col),main="Initial");

breaks = c(seq(r@data@min, 2, length.out=20), r@data@max);
image(r, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", col= rev(col), breaks=breaks,main="JacobF");` I want everything else same except for the pixels where value is greater than zlim the colour should be the first color of my palette("darkred"). I hope its clear now.

Comment: If I understand your question, the revised code should do what you are asking.